# jQuery .find is not working in live web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get some dom element from a site, I have 10 or more sites for this stuff. I have done with one site using following code but it is not working for the next URL.

```
$.get('http://www.example.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph576bfc568f54d', function (response) {
    var thumbnail = $(response).find('meta[property="og:image"]');
    var thumbUrl = $(thumbnail).attr('content');
    console.log(thumbUrl);
});
```

I have tried above code. For other sites it works, but not for this.

If you want to try you need to also use this above first script.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
    if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
        var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
        options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
        //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
    }
});

$.get('http://www.example.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph576bfc568f54d', function (response) {
    var thumbnail = $(response).find('meta[property="og:image"]');
    var thumbUrl = $(thumbnail).attr('content');
    console.log(thumbUrl);
});
```

Comment: It have adult content, but i need to get meta tag content from this page.

Comment: you should explain what exactly isnt working

Comment: I did change the URL. It's not important what site it is, and that URL is not appropriate for here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to strip down the the protocol portion of the Url before passing it as a parameter to `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`.

Try this:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
    if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
        var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
        options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url.split('//')[1];
    }
});
```

As of parsing the `response`, I think it's a waist of resources to parse the entire response into a DOM tree of its own while it might be better to extract the value using simple string methods.

However, your current approach is failing because jQuery would not create a DOM tree for you if you're passing the entire response (using `$(response)`).

Try this instead:

```
$.get('http://www.example.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph576bfc568f54d', function (response) {
    var parser = new DOMParser(),
        doc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/html");

    console.log(doc.querySelectorAll('meta[property="og:image"]')[0].content);
});
```

Comment: its giving me error `GET http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fview_video.php%3Fviewkey%3Dph576bfc568f54d 404 (Invalid host)`

Comment: `GET http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.example.com%2Fview_video.php%3Fviewkey%3Dph576bfc568f54d 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: @PankajPawar, Sorry. Forgot to remove `encodeUriComponent()`. Try now

Comment: really sorry haim770 but

`[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[232]]
length
:
0
prevObject
:
jQuery.fn.init[232]
__proto__
:
Object[0]`

console showing length 0.

Comment: Hey, dude it works! thanks. i am not getting why we need to define again its text/html and DOMParser()

Comment: @PankajPawar, Because `$(entireHtmlDocumentAsString)` will not work as you expect. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/ though